# Inheritance vs std::function for writing platform-independent code

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization

I'm evaluating the possibility of using lambdas instead of inheritance for writing platform independent code. I often have to pass callbacks (for logging, for HW communication, and so on).
Typically, one would use inheritance and virtual function to achieve what want to do. In the example below, the `test` class would be shared in a separate file between different platforms and compilers (from PC to small MCUs).
`priv_test` would be defined by the user of the `test` class, and would be project-dependent.

```
volatile int a = 0;

struct test
{
    virtual int callback(int i) = 0;

    test()
    {}

    void do_something()
    {
        a += callback(5);
    }
};

struct priv_test:public test
{
    using test::test;
    int callback(int i) override
    {
        return i+2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    priv_test instance;
    instance.do_something();
}
```

in this simple example, the compiler output is very well optimized: https://godbolt.org/z/P16cMP

The other way would be to use lambdas like so:

```
#include <functional>

volatile int a = 0;

struct test
{
    struct conf
    {
        std::function<int(int)> callback;
    };

    test(const conf& config) : config(config)
    {}

    void do_something()
    {
        a += config.callback(5);
    }

private:
    const conf& config;
};

int main()
{
    test::conf config{[](int i) {return i+2;}};

    test instance(config);
    instance.do_something();
}
```

In the latter case, it is rather easy to use for the end user, and quite flexible. However, the compiler output is quite big, even if it is achieving the same functionality (in this example): https://godbolt.org/z/P4zPnP

1. So, how would you write classes needing some sort of callbacks, and why?
2. Do you think of other code architecture that are better than the ones offered above?
3. Can the second version be further optimized?

PS : Code size and performance matter to me. Also usually I have only a few instances of these kind classes.

Comment: Sounds like something you can easily benchmark.

Comment: This doesn't look like a fair comparison. The first version is only so much smaller because the type of `instance` is known at compile time, so everything is statically dispatched, inlined, and simplified. The second version is truly doing the dynamic dispatch. It also contains a heap allocation (which your first version doesn't), and does a check for an empty `std::function`. Unless your actual situation requires no heap allocation, has no possibility of a missing/invalid function, and has a statically known call (in which case you should be using functors), this example isn't representative.

Comment: @HTNW Thanks for your answer. I'm not familiar with functors. Why would they be more suited when everything is known at compile time?

Comment: My suspicions are confirmed: [If I throw a `std::unique_ptr` around your "optimized" code](https://godbolt.org/z/qj49qn), its size becomes comparable to the `std::function` version. Actually, on my machine, with `-Os`, the object file for the `std::function` version is a few bytes smaller, and the executable is somehow 2/3 the size of the virtual function version... I'm not sure why. (I also tried using a plain `*`, but the compiler saw through that one and everything was statically known, so again not a good comparison.) The finickyness just shows you how measuring this stuff is hard.

Comment: Anyway: using functors means using templates, which means everything must be known at compile time and means that the compiler can do more optimizations (hopefully). Your functions/classes take functor objects as argument/fields (`template<typename F> foo(F callback);`), and then call the `operator()`s (`{ int i = ...; callback(i); }`). The compiler generates a copy of `foo` for each different `F`, so it can e.g. inline `F::operator=` into `foo`. Lambda expressions are shorthand for a new anonymous "functor class" and they create functor objects, which supports this pattern.

Comment: Of course, if code size is an issue, this is only viable if you know that the applicable optimizations outweigh the fact that the templates are going to copy everything many times over.

Comment: @HTNW I've tried your functors solution, and it is indeed very well optimized by the compiler. This led me to ask this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63436695/how-to-tell-to-a-functor-templated-class-user-what-functor-operator-signature you may know the answer