# How to tell to a functor templated class user what functor operator() signature he has to write?

Tags: c++

Consider this meaningless example of a templated class using functors as template arguments: (godbolt [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TdeGh7))

```
volatile int a = 0;
volatile int b = 0;

template <typename F, typename F2>
class testclass
{
    public:

    bool doOperation(int a)
    {
        F f;
        F2 f2;
        f(a);
        return f2(a);
    }
};

int main()
{
    struct MyFunctor1
    {
        bool operator()(int b)
        {
            a+=b;
            return true;
        }
    };

    struct MyFunctor2
    {
        bool operator()(int b)
        {
            a-=b;
            return false;
        }
    };

    testclass<MyFunctor1, MyFunctor2> instance;
    instance.doOperation(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Let's consider the `testclass` user does not know the internals of the class. So he does not know what operator() signatures for the functor he has to provide for the template argument.

In this example case, how can I tell the user to pass a functor whose operator() signature is as following: `bool (int)`?
And how can I force the compiler to check it?

Comment: Are you looking for [C++20 concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)?

Comment: `return f2(a);` would check that `f2` can be called with int and return type convertible to bool. (even if error reported might not necessary be clear).

Comment: @Jarod42 C++20 concepts would be a solution, but for now I'm stuck with C++17 for a while (embedded projects). However, I will try the C++20 solution out of curiosity.

Comment: We can mimic some c++ concepts functionalities with SFINAE.

Comment: Templates are evaluated at compile time, so they are checked automatically. If the functor's argument cannot be converted from `int` or its result type cannot converted to `bool`, the compiler will emit an error. If the conversion is possible but problematic, i.e. because it irreversibly changes the value of the variable, the compiler will emit a warning if it is configured appropriatly.